# How to create a guest account on Android phones?

Tags: security, lock-screens, privacy, accounts, anti-theft

I want to create a "phantom account" or "guest account" on my smartphone Android to let other people accessing and using my phone without needing to enter the fingerprint pattern, on the one hand, and avoiding at the same time the risk that others can access my personal info, as far as I'm logged into my accounts (WhatsApp, messenger and so on).

Whoever accesses my system through a "guest account" would be able to connect to the internet, modifying settings and switching gps on, etc., but **wouldn't be able to access my personal data and apps**.

I'm focusing on something similar to what happens on Windows when you configure some anti-theft softwares (see ->  https://help.eset.com/antitheft/en-US/issue_no_fakeuseraccount.html).

I wonder: given that it's possible to create a phantom account on Windows, may I obtain something similar on Android too, to protect my privacy while I want to let others to use my phone?

- - - - U P D A T E - - - - - -

I read right now that Asus had removed Guest Mode on all Android Marshmallow firmwares. Can you suggest any way to bring on the above mentioned feature?

Comment: Guest is a built-in feature starting from Android L (5.0). It's in **Settings** -> **Users** -> **Guest Mode**.

Comment: Please see https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2865483?hl=en. @iBug that alone suffices as an answer.

Comment: What phone and ROM are you using? Custom ROMs are likely to strip this feature.

Comment: I hold an Asus Zenfone 3 max with Android 7.0. Where can I find info abut my rom, are they maybe under "Build number"?

Answer (score 1):

Guest is a built-in feature as of from Android L (5.0).

It's in **Settings** -> **Users** -> **Guest Mode**

Pros:

- Guest data is isolated and gets wiped every time G Mode is disabled (device returned to owner)
- Guest has limited access to existing apps, and the access is configurable

Cons: Unknown

And here's [Google Support](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2865483) link provided by *Firelord*.

Comment: I have 7.0 but I cannot find how to configure it

Comment: @beeshyams Tested with my OnePlus 5 (FP scanner + Android N)